# How to find the page views per page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any plugin available for finding page views per post/page in wordpress? I see in my website already has google analytics plugin. from that I could find traffic, users, session details and all. But I need the page views per page/post, user geographical information and user language etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all the information that you need are available in Google Analytics, [read this guide on moz](https://moz.com/blog/absolute-beginners-guide-to-google-analytics)  in order to understand it.

another simple solution for you might be wp [statistics](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-statistics/) which will gives you lots of information about your users.

another solution might be [w3counter](https://www.w3counter.com/) or [jetpack](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/), all of them work perfectly and it depends on information that you need from your users to choose which one

Answer (score 1):

You can see page hits either via the Statistics->Pages menu or by going to the WordPress Pages menu, there will be a hits column in the page list (which you can click to get more detail). Also if you edit a page you will see the hits in the “Publish” widget and the “Hit Statistics” widget.

Comment: or use this plugin for wordpress: https://wordpress.org/plugins/pageviews/
download, unzip, upload on your ftp, install and activate from Control panel